# Is there a CPU that runs Java in microcode?

Tags: java, performance, cpu

Java is a beautifully crafted OO language but the first thing I noticed is how slow it is (compared to C++). This is probably because it has to go through another layer of translation (the VM) instead of running directly in the CPU's native microcode.

My question: Do you know of any attempts to create Java-specific CPU's that run Java natively without requiring the software-implemented VM?

Comment: People (rightfully) complaining about "Java is slow" complainment in N... (N-1)... (Also, a special-purpose CPU that runs Java bytecode would very likely end up much slower than a modern desktop CPU running a regular JVM).

Comment: Well, Assembly is even faster, but the time you gain on performance, becomes development time (and multiplyed by 100 factor maybe...)

Comment: @skaffman By slow I meant slower than a comparable program in C++. Try running Eclipse (which AFAIK was written in Java) inside a VMWare VM and see what I mean.

Comment: @digEmAll This question is not comparing Java to other languages. My question was regarding a hardware implementation of the Java VM, which @skaffman answered. I will accept his answer unless a better one comes along.

Comment: @Android Eve: I know, I was provocatively commenting your sentence: `"...how slow it is (compared to C++)"` ;-)

Comment: Java has slower startup time compared to C++, but after warmup it can achieve comparable performance, or even better performance if server JVM is being used.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor

Comment: @Android Eve Eclipse is hardly a good example of Java speed.  Try Minecraft or IntelliJ as your base if you insist on comparing GUIs written by arbitrary people.  Java does tend to be about the same speed as C++ if you are not allocating memory for long-term apps.  If you are allocating small amounts of heap memory on both Java and C++, java can be slightly faster than C++ over time.  For most operations Java tends to be 1/2 the speed (twice as slow as c++), when you compare this to 10x slower for python and 100x slower for ruby... Java is screaming fast.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sun designed the [picoJava](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PicoJava) processor about 10 years ago, but it never went anywhere - there was no market for it at the time, and modern VMs render the concept pretty pointless.

Then there's the fledgling [ARM Jazelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) architecture.

Comment: +1 for this precise piece of information. I will read it shortly and try to understand why it never went anywhere.

Comment: @Android: It never went anywhere because there was no market for it, and because the JVMs of the day *were* slow. It'll go nowhere today, because the modern JVMs are *not* slow.

Comment: @saffman the Wikipedia article you just brought says "speeding bytecode execution up to 20 times, compared to standard Intel CPU with a JVM." -- This is what I mean by "slow". We take faster CPU nowadays for granted but this is not very energy efficient... By slow I mean slow**er**.

Comment: @Android: There's no citation for that figure. Just because it's written on wikipedia doesn't make it true. It's likely to be years out of date.

Comment: @Android Eve: Every commonly used JVM has a sophisticated JIT compiler than intelligently native-compiles methods that would benefit from it. So nowadays executing bytecode natively is fairly useless.

Comment: @GregS, I am not happy with the speed Eclipse runs inside my Windows XP VM (in VMWare). Do you know whether there is a JIT version of Eclipse that runs faster then the officially distributed one?

Answer (score 7):

The only reference I found so far to this conundrum is the following article:

http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=59958

While I was initially interested in first knowing whether there are Java-CPU's and what they are, this thread sheds some light on *why* I haven't heard of any (until I read the learned replies here). The last comment, by Alex Besogonov, seems to be the best explanation:

> Java bytecode is NOT suited to be run
>   on real hardware. It's stack-based, so
>   pipelining goes out of the window. In
>   theory, one can do on-the-fly
>   translation from stack-based to
>   register-based machine, but it'll
>   require A LOT of transistors.
>
> So in reality, it's ALWAYS more
>   effective to JIT-compile Java bytecode
>   and then run it on a common CPU. There
>   is one exception JVMs for low-power
>   devices where the speed of hardware
>   JVM is not a problem (remember Forth
>   CPUs).
>
> Of course, hardware can still provide
>   few features to speed up JVMs. Like
>   hardware-assisted forwarding pointers
>   which allow to create fast real-time
>   compacting pauseless GC (I assume Azul
>   hardware has this support).

This is very interesting. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

[Azul Systems](http://www.azulsystems.com/) designs systems from the ground up with (massive services running on) Java in mind, including hardware-assisted garbage collection.

There's also [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) for compiling Java to native code, though it is not a complete implementation of Java.

Comment: But the *whole point* of Azul's Vega-3 CPU is that it *does not* implement JVML bytecode. It is simply a well-designed, orthogonal CPU. The smarts are in the JVML-to-native compiler (which is actually just a licensed variant of Sun's/Oracle's C2 compiler which is part of the HotSpot JVM) and not in the CPU. The people who founded Azul *came* from Sun's Java CPU projects, and they did it this way precisely because they realized that implementing JVML in the CPU is *not* faster, it is *slower*, because it throws away the massive dynamic optimization potential.

Comment: +1 for this information. I hope that this thread will become a reference for existing attempts.

Comment: @Jörg - yes, this isn't a very good answer to the question asked. but since it sounds like a fairly exploratory question (has anyone done X? instead of why doesn't Y work?) going off in a bit of a tangent seems appropriate.

Comment: @JörgWMittag what do you mean by dynamic optimization potential?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [JOP](http://www.jopdesign.com/)

It's open source and you can try it on your own hardware.