# Can the JVM (and therefore Java) run on a bare cpu/hardware somehow?

Tags: java

Can the JVM (and therefore Java) run on a bare CPU? If it can, what happens with calls to things like System.out.println (there's no output device to go to…)?

Comment: You ought to define what you mean by a bare CPU. This can mean all sorts of things: cpu without peripherals such as a mouse, keyboard, screen, etc., physical cpu without other hardware like RAM or heatsink, or even the semiconductor chip and nothing else.

Comment: Short answer: no. The JVM needs an OS to run.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "bare". If you mean execute JVM instructions on the bare metal, then no, there's no microprocessor that will do that. If you're after a JVM that is small enough that it will fit in / run on a typical 8 bit micro, then HaikuVM is a project that does just that.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359343/is-there-a-cpu-that-runs-java-in-microcode The second part of your question can't be answered unless you identify a particular implementation - every one will be different.

Comment: Maybe it's better to imagine that the JVM could run **as** a CPU.  The JVM can be viewed as a software emulation of a CPU.  It has a stack and op codes.  While it's possible that the JVM could be implemented in silicon, the frequent updates to it make it a better candidate for software emulation.

Comment: @Michael Berry If it's running without an OS on the HaikuVM how do parts of Java like System.out.println work?

Comment: @QuiQu Obviously you'd have to provide the 'OS' stuff such as I/O (console, files, sockets,...) yourself. That is why nobody will actually endeavor such a daunting task.

Comment: @M.leRutte In other words, Java is just exclusively for programming where those facilities are available, right?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of--Java was initially made to run on cable boxes and such with a minimal overhead (believe it or not) without much of an OS presence.

However The JVM executable (Java.exe) is customized to different cpu architectures/OSes, this is the part you'd have to re-write, and I think it's probably already written in C (At least mostly).

So in summary, you could make a Java.exe equivalent that runs on bare metal, however you could not do it in Java

Comment: Hmm. I'm imagining Java running without an OS, and I'm confused as to what happens to so many of its features that interact with the OS, like System.out.println. My confusion may be due to some misconceptions, so please correct me if I'm not understanding something fundamental.

Comment: Your java runtime (Java.exe on windows) has to be different for every CPU/OS combo.  Take a look at this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS  I think it's pretty much what we're talking about.  There was also an open-source attempt a while ago, not sure what happened to it.